# Feature extraction methods for grayscale image

Tags: image, image-processing, grayscale, feature-extraction, lbph-algorithm

I am working on IR image, which is a grayscale image of a person moving his arms. So anyone tell me which feature extraction will be good to capture the motion information? like Local binary Pattern (LBP) captures the texture information similarly (Histogram of Oriented Gradient) HOG counts occurrences of gradient orientation. Are there any other methods which will be useful fo grayscale image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are useful. But there are several descriptors and feature detectors with higher information extraction ability. Fist, Hessian features detector to detect blobs on the image is rather power tool. Second, you can also build descriptors for those features you are found by SURF or FREAK. It will give you more robust tracking.

Comment: Thanks.. but about the LBP i read that i can extract the texture information so is it fine to extract the texture information from the grayscale image? i think that grayscale image of person will have similar texture.. i am not sure maybe i am wrong

Comment: Regarding the texture information - yes, you can do it with grayscale image. But texture information, especially LBP is not better descriptor. Since only pixel values are used for building the description, pure LBP is very unstable because of noise.  The FREAK proposes using mean of vicinity of neighbourhood pixels as the value, and vicinity size depended on the distance to the central pixel.

Comment: is it possible to get directional information using HOG? as I read from the Wikipedia that HOG counts occurrences of gradient orientation in localized portions, it means that we can get the directional information also?

Comment: Do you have only one image or series? What is the information that you need (direction, speed, distance)? We can get gradient directional information of a feature  using HOG as well SURF, SIFT, FREAK but it is not information about moving of object.

Comment: I have a series of images of a person moving his arm. I want to know that can I get directional information using HOG?  distance and speed is also possible using HOG?

Comment: Ok. No, HOG is not designed for it, as well others descriptors. They intended for description a feature point. To obtain parameters you are interested in, you should at first detect features on 1st image and 2nd. Then build theirs descriptors using HoG (or any), then you should compare this key-points using the descriptor that have been built. Finally, you have to calculate distance between common points from both images.

Comment: You mean from HOG I can not extract the dominant directional information between the image 1 and image 2?